# Position zip code label correctly in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, zipcode, centroid

I am drawing a list of zip code areas in google maps and I am trying to write a label with the zip code over the area. I can do this just fine, except that I am using the centriod of the area to position the label, but some areas are shaped irregularly and the centroid falls outside the area itself. Here is an example of what I mean:

[image]

Watch zip code 81151, how it shows up on top of the area for zip code 81123 rather than on top of his own area.

Does anyone know of a better algorithm to correctly position the zip code on top of an irregular area, rather than using the area's centroid?

Comment: Are you using google.maps.LatLngBounds.getCenter()?

Comment: Hi AJC. I just saw this post while searching for my query. Could you pls tell me how I can show these zipcode numbers as a label over the plotted zipcodes. Thanks

Comment: Hi @AJC. I have the exact requirement, Could you please tell me how I can have the exact google map? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation and google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate functions.

for example. get a boundary point and the center point of the polygon and use the function '**google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate ({centerpoint}, {bundaypoint}, {distance})**'
then you verify that the resulting point is in the area of ​​the polygon with
'**google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation ({resultPoint}, {polygonObject})**' function.

GetBounds function:

```
if (!google.maps.Polygon.prototype.getBounds) {
            google.maps.Polygon.prototype.getBounds = function (latLng) {
                var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                var paths = this.getPaths();
                var path;
                for (var p = 0; p < paths.getLength() ; p++) {
                    path = paths.getAt(p);
                    for (var i = 0; i < path.getLength() ; i++) {
                        bounds.extend(path.getAt(i));
                    }
                }
                return bounds;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks! This was more like what I was looking. I am able to build a more elegant solution, provided I put limits on the amount of zip codes I calculate at once.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a couple of weeks ago and didn't find any algorithm(maybe there isn't any).

Finally I found a fusionTable with the desired data(I've used a fusionTable too to store the boundaries, so it was easy to merge the tables).

Maybe you can do the same, a quick search gave the following result: https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1VwApbjvZ--YKE6fRT_StuJ7jd2o0r2jLUmGwQnI

e.g. for the zip 81151 the coordinate is placed there more to the west, maybe this table fits your needs

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a good idea. However, this definitely seems like the correct route if you want to show all zip codes in a map, however getting and maintaining that data might be more complicated than calculating the position for a few zip codes at a time. Maybe I should have clarified that.